# Changing the pivot doesn't change the coordinate system origin

Tags: scenekit, scnnode

I'm pretty new to SceneKit and I've stumbled upon a pretty odd, in my opinion, behaviour.

Changing a node pivot move the point by which it's anchored to its parent as the pivot is placed at the point specified by the `position` of the node itself. This is fine, but then I tried to add a child node to one with its pivot moved (translated only) and the child node (with default position of `(0,0,0)`) placed itself at the geometric center of its parent, a cylinder created with `SCNCylinder`, instead at its moved pivot.

It's not a problem to recalculate the position to place the child relative to the parent pivot using the transformation that moves the pivot, but I was wondering if there is a valid reason for not moving the coordinate system along with the pivot of the node as I didn't find anything on the web regarding this fact.